# Update svg path from typed arrays

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, typed-arrays, asm.js

**What is the best way to construct SVG paths from typed arrays?**

Such arrays seem to be the best way to transfer data from code compiled for asm.js to other JavaScript snippets.

Various possible approaches come to mind. One option would be constructing the `d` attribute text in the source code for the asm.js application. But that string would include a lot of numbers, and the emscripten implementation of `sprintf` is too general to give good performance here. So I doubt that this approach has any chances competing.

So the data should pass from generated asm.js code to hand-written JavaScript not as text but instead as numbers. One possibility is using **two typed arrays** (which are in fact different views of the same `ArrayBuffer`). One to hold the segment types and the other the associated coordinates. This data can then be used in hand-written code to either compute a **string** for the `d` attribute, or to build a segment list using the **[`SVGPathSegList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegList)** from the SVG DOM API.

I've experimented with both these alternatives here:
http://jsperf.com/svg-path-from-typed-arrays.

<s>Neither approach seems particularly fast.</s> *(Edit: it seems I mistook the thounsand's separator for a decimal separator. If this is right, and I had almost ten thousand operations per second, instead of only ten, then this is quite acceptable)*

<s>So</s> *Still* I wonder, is there some alternative I missed?
Is there a way to make this kind of operation *even* faster?
Feel free to [edit](http://jsperf.com/svg-path-from-typed-arrays/edit) my jsperf if you want to try new alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my current best solution. I won't mind at all if someone comes up with a more clever one. The code number associated with each line type matches those from [`SVGPathSeg.pathSegType`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathSeg__pathSegType). So “close” is `1`, “move absolute” is `2` and so on.

```
var letters = [" ? ", " Z ", " M ", " m ", " L ", " l ",
               " C ", " c ", " Q ", " q ", " A ", " a ",
               " H ", " h ", " V ", " v ", " S ", " s ", " T ", " t "];
var numbers = [  0  ,   0  ,   2  ,   2  ,   2  ,   2  ,
                 6  ,   6  ,   4  ,   4  ,   7  ,   7  ,
                 1  ,   1  ,   1  ,   1  ,   4  ,   4  ,   2  ,   2  ]; 

function buildPathString(elt, types, coordinates) {
  var i, t, c, nc, d = "", ci = 0;
  for (i = 0; i != types.length; ++i) {
    t = types[i];
    nc = numbers[t];
    c = coordinates.subarray(ci, ci + nc);
    d += letters[t] + Array.prototype.join.call(c, " ");
    ci += nc;
  }
  elt.setAttribute("d", d);
}
```